# looking for a probabilty formula to use

Tags: probability, distributions

I have 15 sets (call them A-O) containing 9 scores each (call them 1-9), so 135 different scores. Those 135 scores have a basically normal distribution.

I’m taking those scores and adding 9 of them together, three each from three different sets, to get a total score. So scores 1, 2, & 3 from set A, scores 4, 5, & 6 from set B, and scores 7, 8, & 9 from set C, for example.

What I’m trying to determine is **what is the distribution of the different combinations of total scores**. Is it similar/related to the normal distribution of the individual scores? **And how would I go about determining the probability of any one total score being above or below any number N**?

Because I can pick 84 different combinations of scores from a single set (1-2-3, 1-2-4, 1-2-5, etc.), the numbers get too big to brute force calculate really quickly – it looks like just over 1.6 billion combinations of individual scores are possible.

Any help with a formula or links/places to learn the math to get me to an answer are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: We need a little more information to be confident of any answer. What matters most is how you select the sets and the scores from them: are these independent uniform selections or something else?  What matters a little is how the 135 scores are spread throughout the sets.  At one extreme, the scores are sorted and the top 9 put into the first set, the next 9 into the next set, and so on.  At another extreme the sets are chosen to contain the widest possible ranges, perhaps by putting the sorted scores of ranks 1, 10, 19, 127 in the first set, ranks 2, 11, 20, ..., 128 in the second, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Scores are independent of one another, both overall and within sets. And the selections of scores from each set when computing each total is random. And as far as how the scores are spread out, that's random too - some sets contain generally higher scores, some generally contain lower scores, some have a wide variety of scores, some have a small StdDev to the set. All scores are within a pretty small range (between 0-12), but are all different - so some have differences at the 4th or 5th decimal point.

Comment: Here are the sets:  
*A {2.3335,2.6121,2.7997,2.9208,3.1983,3.9477,4.3959,4.9949,5.4731}
*B {2.6887,4.1779,4.3509,4.9238,5.1883,5.5003,5.8761,6.7282,7.476}
*C {1.2973,2.1547,2.1769,3.6378,4.1299,4.1924,4.5986,4.8854,6.1742}
*D {3.5586,4.1708,5.0503,5.9793,6.4038,7.7669,8.0653,8.471,10.7723}
*E {3.2432,3.9102,4.5951,6.264,7.3194,7.3536,7.413,9.6371,10.1491}
*F {0.8832,1.8813,2.1153,3.0985,3.4575,4.2556,4.7235,5.7283,6.0961}
*G {0.5964,1.728,2.6757,2.8248,2.8907,3.1175,3.2661,3.6074,5.5991}
*H {1.249,2.9393,3.9766,4.7873,4.8456,4.9613,5.0007,5.654,5.8287}

Comment: *I {3.0216,3.3796,3.9112,4.8028,5.7208,5.8774,9.1939,9.8718,10.0294}
*J {3.878,4.3092,5.6073,5.6873,6.4788,6.6079,7.4117,11.0137,11.5}
*K {0.0346,0.3326,2.4553,3.0403,3.1626,4.741,4.7597,8.6442,9.9608}
*L {1.4269,1.8395,2.0497,2.1866,2.2991,2.9902,3.0761,3.1275,4.5872}
*M {2.9222,3.2808,3.6817,4.3557,5.1523,5.515,7.7199,7.8305,8.1315}
*N {2.8551,4.3359,5.9157,6.9338,7.0469,7.7702,8.2916,10.548,11.5}
*O {0.7988,0.8476,2.0953,2.9258,3.8822,4.9247,5.1236,5.9764,8.1879}